# zoom is not function in porto magento 2 demo 1 theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, magento2.1

I'm frontend developer. I'm using `Smartwave porto magento 2 demo 1 theme`. Suddenly on product detail page zoom on hover function not working. I have uploaded old `pub - static` folder where zoom is working properly. But here is still error in console zoom is not function. Where to check error? even i copied whole zoom function code where `zoom function` is called. Still no luck. Please let me know. What I'm missing or where to check because I'm not magento guy. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Magento 2.2.4 and Porto theme. I minified (*not bundled*) the Javascript, and because of that, the error occured. I'm currently on Porto **3.0.6**

I think it's because Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/web/js/jquery.zoom.min.js is included in the minified files, but does not use RequireJS. So it's loaded before jQuery is loaded (in my case anyway).

So I deleted the loading script in my *child theme* this way in Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml in the  container:

```
<head>
    <remove src="Magento_Catalog::js/jquery.zoom.min.js" />
</head>
```

And added this in my requirejs-config.js (Smartwave/CHILDTHEMENAME/requirejs-config.js, to include it:

```
var config = {
    deps: [
        'Magento_Catalog/js/jquery.zoom.min'
    ],
    shim: {
        'Magento_Catalog/js/jquery.zoom.min':
            {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
    }
};
```